# How to download the latest version of software from a site using a script?

Tags: windows, script, download, batch-file

For example:

How to download the latest Google chrome from their site using a Bach file or any kind of scripting language (python,ruby etc)?

its the concept i am looking for.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make an educated guess as to what the path is to the new file. If there is a specific format, e.g. "chrome_v***.exe" and you know what number comes next, this is as easy as downloading any file and may be done in all scripting language. However, it must be program- or pattern specific.

Comment: Ok so I monitor the software i want to download history and see the way their numbering system works and then simply download via FTP with a script using some sort of counter if i understand correctly. Thanks very much.

Comment: That would be the way to do it, yes.